# Change default style or hide mobile select element (without losing its functionality)

Tags: css, forms, mobile, select

I am trying to create a alternative style to the select list on mobile. What I want is use my own styled button to activate the select list options. On iPhone and Android this gives you a popup with the options. I got this working by applying the button styles to the label for the select element. However, I am unable to properly hide the select element from view without also disabling its functionality. Does anyone know how to do this?

My html looks like this:

```
<label class="button-sort">
    <select>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Do not understand, sorry ;-) Also, `LABEL` elements do not wrap anything - the way to use one in your case would be `<label for="select1" class="button-sort" />`, that's it. No `</label>` after the `</select>`. In other words, the `SELECT` element is *not* a child of a `LABEL` element.

Comment: Partly right. Actually the for is not needed in my case since I wrap the select in a label. There are 2 ways to associate a label with an input element, by using for="" or wrap the label around the elemnt. Anyway.. I'm not sure how I can carify what i mean. I want to hide the select element, but not its options. Clicking the label should bring up the options, but the default select style should be hidden. I simply want to replace the default style of the input element with my own.

Comment: Ok, but select element is nothing but its options and you don't have any input element at all (ref. "...input element with my own"). Perhaps you would like to write your own select UI with say, JavaScript?

Comment: That would be fine, but can you call the default behaviour of a select element on mobile that way? Thats the reason why I am not using a javascript alternative like jquery ui yet.

Comment: mobile is no different than desktop these days. Aim standards, not implementations. However, I still do not understand what you want :-) Maybe instead of explaning HOW you want to do things, you can explain your goals? I mean what are you building? If you want to select things, just give the user the `select` control and forget about fancy stuff, that may turn out to be a winner.